# Using Visual Studio 08's Installer, how can I install a Web Application into a path that is NOT under C:\Inetpub?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-applications, installation

I'm trying to alter our existing installer for a web application, so that the files are located not at C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\OurProduct but rather under C:\Program Files\OurCompany\OurProduct, so far with little success.

Any help/suggestions will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [change the physical path of the virtual directory content.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754640(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: Looks like I'm restricted to using IIS 5.1/6.0, I neglected to mention that earlier :(

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the installation path from the user during setup, you could have a look at this project here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/WebServieInstaller.aspx
it explains how to get the local installation path from the user himself.